# How Can I Solve the Collection View Blinking Issue? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xcode7

I'm working on a collection view project which uses the Parse as the backend server. And not quite sure here why my collection view blinks every time it gets appeared on the screen.. The second cell of the collection view gives me a blink a second after the view got appeared on the screen, with the image of the third cell. So, can you guys help me to solve this problem? And this is my current file looks like..

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)

if PFUser.currentUser() == nil {
    // the user hasn't logged in yet
    showLogin()
} else {
    // the user logged in, do something else
    fetchInterests()

    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
    center.addObserverForName("NewInterestCreated", object: nil, queue: queue, usingBlock: { (notification) -> Void in

        if let newInterest = notification.userInfo?["newInterestObject"] as? Interest {
            if !self.interestWasDisplayed(newInterest) {
                self.interests.insert(newInterest, atIndex: 0)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })

}

func interestWasDisplayed(newInterest: Interest) -> Bool {
for interest in interests {
    if interest.objectId! == newInterest.objectId! {
        return true
    }
}
return false



override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()



// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 480.0 {
    let flowLayout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(250.0, 300.0)
}

configureUserProfile()



func fetchInterests()
{
let currentUser = User.currentUser()!
let interestIds = currentUser.interestIds
if interestIds?.count > 0
{
    let interestQuery = PFQuery(className: Interest.parseClassName())
    interestQuery.orderByDescending("updatedAt")
    interestQuery.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.NetworkElseCache
    interestQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: interestIds)

    interestQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let interestObjects = objects as [PFObject]? {
                self.interests.removeAll()
                for interestObject in interestObjects {
                    let interest = interestObject as! Interest
                    self.interests.append(interest)
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in viewDidAppear, you are calling the reloadData on the collectionView too many times.
Make sure that the reload data in the block is called on the main thread.